# Python requests - download cut short

Tags: python, python-3.x, download, web-scraping, python-requests

I've recently been trying to scrape a site that contains chemistry exam tests in pdf using Python. I used requests for python and everything was going well, until some of the downloads were cut short at a very small size i.e. 2KB. What's curious though - it happens completely at random with every run of the script the files cut are different. I've been scratching my head for a while now and decided to ask here. Downloading them manually probably would have proved faster by now, but I want to know why the script isn't working, for future reference.

I've written the script to be asynchronous, thus it occurred to me that I could have been DoSing the server. However, I've replaced every Pool with a synchronous for loop, even adding time.sleep() here and there - it didn't help. Using this approach none of the files were fully downloaded - practically every single one stopping at 2KB.

Please forgive me if the question is naive or my mistake is foolish as I am only a hobby programmer. I'll be grateful for any help.

P.S. I've intercepted the headers using Postman from Chrome, without them the response was 500, however I won't include them as they contain session ids that would enable you to login into my account.

**The script is as follows:**

```
from shutil import copyfileobj
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

from requests import get
from time import sleep

titles = {
    "95": "Budowa atomu. Układ okresowy pierwiastków chemicznych",
    "96": "Wiązania chemiczne",
    "97": "Systematyka związków nieorganicznych",
    "98": "Stechiometria",
    "99": "Reakcje utleniania-redukcji. Elektrochemia",
    "100": "Roztwory",
    "101": "Kinetyka chemiczna",
    "102": "Reakcje w wodnych roztworach elektrolitów",
    "103": "Charakterystyka pierwiastków i związków chemicznych",
    "104": "Chemia organiczna jako chemia związków węgla",
    "105": "Węglowodory",
    "106": "Jednofunkcyjne pochodne węglowodorów",
    "107": "Wielofunkcyjne pochodne węglowodorów",
    "108": "Arkusz maturalny"
}
#collection = {"120235": "Chemia nieorganiczna", "120586": "Chemia organiczna"}

url = "https://e-testy.terazmatura.pl/print/%s/quiz_%s/%s"

def downloadTest(id):
    with ThreadPool(2) as tp:
        tp.starmap(downloadActualTest, [(id, "blank"), (id, "key")])


def downloadActualTest(id, dataType):
    name = titles[str(id)]

    if id in range(95, 104):
        collectionId = 120235
    else:
        collectionId = 120586

    if dataType == "blank":
        with open("Pulled Data/%s - pusty.pdf" % name, "wb") as test:
            print("Downloading: " + url % (collectionId, id, "blank") + '\n')
            r = get(url % (collectionId, id, "blank"),
                    stream=True,
                    headers=headers)
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            copyfileobj(r.raw, test)
    elif dataType == "key":
        with open("Pulled Data/%s - klucz.pdf" % name, "wb") as test:
            print("Downloading: " + url % (collectionId, id, "key") + '\n')
            r = get(url % (collectionId, id, "key"),
                    stream=True,
                    headers=headers)
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            copyfileobj(r.raw, test)


with ThreadPool(3) as p:
    p.map(downloadTest, range(95, 109))
```

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error then the downloads aren't being "cut short" - you're getting an error page. The 500 error page should give some idea of what is going wrong on the server.

Comment: Perhaps I've phrased it wrong. I am not actually getting the 500 error page while running the script. I only get error 500 when I don't include headers in the request. (which I've cut out of the code) I include them and despite that downloads are being interrupted at random, resulting with a 2KB file. When opening the file in pdf reader it's a blank page, however it's not empty as evident when opening i.e. with Notepad++. So the error lies somewhere. Today I got an idea to use the script to download some locally hosted files and observe the behaviour, yet to be done.

Comment: Another idea I've had is that perhaps the script exists before the download is complete? Thus interrupting download streams. I don't really know how the threading module behaves in conjunction with requests.